# How to order values in a dictionary in a lexicography order?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code here:

```
def most_popular_book(book_loans):
    vBL = book_loans.values()
    kBL = book_loans.keys()
    items = book_loans.items()
    print items
    kBL = sorted(kBL, key=str.lower)
    mvBL = max(vBL)
    for key,vaule in items:
        if vaule == mvBL:
            return key
```

my goal with this code is to get the key with the biggest value, and if 2 keys have the same values then choose the one that comes first in a lexicography order.

now the first part of the code works fine! however I am having trouble with the second part. 
I read some code on the subject but I haven't been able to find a way to make it work.

*example for how the code should work:*

```
print most_popular_book({'harry potter':['yossi','adam'], 
'lilo and stich':['yossi', "adam"], 'catch-22':['adam'] })

'harry potter'
```

(it should print harry potter)
but my code prints **'lilo and stich'**

*another example:*

```
{'the little prince': ['yossi'], 'harry potter': ['yossi', 'assaf'], 
 'catch-22': ['yossi', 'dana']}

'catch-22'
```

(this output is working correctly)

Comment: You said you want lexicographic order as a criteria, in case two keys have the same amount of values, then `'catch-22'` is correct, because in lexicographic order it comes before than harry potter.

Comment: @CtrlS then why should harry potter be the answer, if the length of the corresponding value is equal to the length of 'catch-22'?

Comment: yeah i noticed that catch is the correct one sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the fully sorted list by:

```
fancy = sorted( book_loans.items(), key = lambda x:(-len(x[1]), x[0]))
```

and takte the first one.

It works by defining a `tuple` as sort-criteria - `tuples` are sorted by 1st value, then 2nd value if 1st value draws etc.

Sorting by `-len()` "inverts" it (you could also specify the `reverse=True` param to sorting - either one works.

```
fancy = sorted( {'harry potter':['yossi','adam'], 'lilo and stich':['yossi', "adam"],
                 'catch-22':['adam'] }.items(), key = lambda x:(-len(x[1]), x[0])) 

print(fancy)
print(fancy[0][0])
```

Output:

```
[('harry potter', ['yossi', 'adam']), ('lilo and stich', ['yossi', 'adam']),
 ('catch-22', ['adam'])]

harry potter
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) if you only want the *most popular book*:

```
def most_popular_book(books):
    result, _ = min(books.items(), key=lambda x: (-len(x[1]), x[0]))
    return result


print(most_popular_book({'harry potter': ['yossi', 'adam'],
                         'lilo and stich': ['yossi', "adam"], 'catch-22': ['adam']}))
print(most_popular_book({'the little prince': ['yossi'], 'harry potter': ['yossi', 'assaf'],
                         'catch-22': ['yossi', 'dana']}))
```

**Output**

```
harry potter
catch-22
```

The idea is the same as in the answer of @PatrickArtner, the only difference being the sorted is *O(nlogn)* and min is *O(n)*. No need to sort the list, only to find the minimum.